# Tilted back up/Tipped back up

Tags: word-choice

The man in the wheelchair got tilted/tipped back up after his wheelchair had fallen on its side.

Are both "tilted" and "tipped" fitting here?

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence it seems that the man was "put upright" or "righted" rather than tipped or tilted.

Both "tipped" and "tilted" mean "pushed from the normal position".  So if the table is tilted then the surface is not horizontal.  In the actual context, wheelchairs don't tip on to their side easily, and righting them isn't easy. So the actual context seems to be an unlikely thing to say.

Comment: To me, "tilted" implies less of an angle than "tipped", so they're not exactly the same. But I agree neither is very idiomatic. "Lifted back up" might be better.